# Группы однородных членов, соединённые составными союзами

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, союзы, однородные-члены

*В числе их регалий должно быть **не только звание** доктора наук и **куча** научных **статей**, **но и работа** в известных компаниях, **членство** в правлениях банков, **участие** в каких-нибудь проектах.*

Могут ли составные союзы соединять не однородные члены, а группы однородных членов?

Тот же вопрос касательно присоединительного союза *а также*. Можно ли с помощью него присоединять не один, а несколько однородных членов?

*Были приглашены родственники, а также коллеги и друзья.*

Comment: Настолько привычное глазу построение, что меня удивляют сомнения по этому поводу.

Answer (score 1):

Как показывают практические примеры,  составные союзы **могут соединять группы однородных членов, например:**

Для полноценной подготовки военного лётчика, способного **не только** управлять самолётом, **но и** выполнять боевые задачи, находить и уничтожать цели,  нужно около 15 лет обучения.  «Известия», 2003.02.17]

Было бы странно, если бы это было невозможно, учитывая, что группировка возможна даже для простых союзов, к к примеру:  И + (И + И)

§ 14. Однородные члены предложения, соединенные двойными или парными союзами

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=102#pp102

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример группировки: И + (И + И).

Comment: Известный пример: Вода давно сбыла в Тереке и быстро сбегала и сохла по канавам (Л. Т.)   http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101